# Why is Linq/Linqpad not recognising primary key of table after a primary key was added to it?

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linqpad

I've got a little script in Linqpad to update some tables in an old DB, some of these tables did not have primary keys set.  After updating those tables and amending a column to be a primary key INT non-nullable field and marking it as the identity column Linqpad is still telling me it can't create/update/delete on that table as it has no primary key.  Is there something else I need to do before Linqpad will acknoweldge these tables now have a primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I realised my problem.  In Linqpad I had constructed a connection based on two databases that the script was running in.  I had been refreshing the original database connection for the database I had been updating.  Simply refreshing the created combined connection in Linqpad resolved the issue.